# Modifying sysctl values inside lxc container

Tags: networking, lxc, container

I have made several linux containers using the normal userspace tools (not docker), and I have been setting up a test environment.

I want to set up two containers to try out heartbeat, which requires the containers to bind to and ip address that is not yet configured, namely net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1

Everytime I try it, it says something like this:

```
user@lxc1:~$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_nonlocal_bind: No such file or directory
```

Also modifying the sysctl.conf file doesnt help. So i did some research, and aparently the guest container binds to the host's /proc/sys (which makes sense), so i modified the hosts value by adding the proper value to the hosts sysctl.conf and then i rebooted the host for good measure:

```
user@host:~$ sudo sysctl -A | grep -i nonlocal
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

as noted above, the host reflects the configuration that i want to see the in guest container, but even after rebooting, the container -still- shows the same problem.

How do i modify these values in the guest container, is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.  You are right that it is related to LXC containers.  I added 
`net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1`
to my LXC host's sysctl.conf , then ran: 
`sysctl -p` (requires root access/sudo)

I did have to reboot the container for the change to take effect.  Also, you will still get `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_nonlocal_bind: No such file or directory`
on the container.  If the functionality works, I am not entirely sure that it is necessary for the same command to be run on the guest container.

I can now access the container via the VIP or the defined IP.

Answer (score 2):

A very late update, but may help someone else.

Did you have /proc mounted within your container?

The error message is saying that it was not able to find a file in the /proc filesystem, which needs (for me) to be explicitly mounted to be available within an LXC container.