# Changing sysctl values in LXC container

Tags: networking, permissions, lxc

Following on from this question:

[Modifying sysctl values inside lxc container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444090/modifying-sysctl-values-inside-lxc-container)

I am hitting a different issue trying to change a sysctl setting within a Linux Container.

With /proc mounted, I get a permissions error if I try to change some network related sysctl settings within the container (I haven't tried non-network settings).

For example:

```
root@container:/# sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=1024000
sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.core.rmem_default'
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Thinking about it further, because the container and host share a kernel, is it even possible for the container to have different values for sysctl parameters from the host?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working extensively with containers recently. I don't think you will be able to set sysctl settings on docker since they do share a kernel.